# Backbone + Jasmine testing AJAX success callback in router

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine

Say I have the following Backbone Router:

```
class App.Routers.ThingsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: -> new App.Collections.ThingsCollection()

  index: ->
    that = this
    @collection.fetch success: ->
      view = new App.Views.ThingsIndex(collection: that.collection)
      $('#app-container').html(view.render().el)
```

I need to write a Jasmine spy that can watch this and ensure that `App.Views.ThingsIndex()` is called. However, as it's AJAX, the following won't work:

```
describe 'index', ->
  @router = new App.Routers.ThingsRouter()
  spyOn(@router.collection, 'fetch')
  fake = { render: -> '' }
  @previewsIndexStub = spyOn(Periscope.Views, 'PreviewsIndex').andReturn(fake)
  @router.index()
  expect(@previewsIndexStub).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Because Jasmine runs the expectation function before the AJAX call can complete. Is there a good way to test a callback like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jasmines built in waitsFor & runs method in order to wait for the ajax call to complete before executing your expect function. See [Jasmine - Asynchronous specs](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs) for documentation on these two functions.

```
describe 'index', ->
  @router = new App.Routers.ThingsRouter()
  spyOn(@router.collection, 'fetch')
  fake = {}; fake.render = -> '';
  @previewsIndexStub = spyOn(Periscope.Views, 'PreviewsIndex').andReturn(fake)
  @router.index()
  waitsFor => @previewsIndexStub.wasCalled
  ###
  Or if you want to wait for the method to be called more than once
  use form waitsFor => @previewsIndexStub.callCount > 1
  ###
  runs => expect(@previewsIndexStub).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: Don't know if this works, as `@previewsIndexStub` doesn't have the `toHaveBeenCalled()` function available to it like `expect(@previewsIndexStub)` does. I get `'undefined' is not a function`

Comment: @clem my bad you'll want to use the variable `wasCalled` instead